# Find "missing arguments" error in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm setting up a script that will `svn add` all new, non-subversion files into subversion and then do a commit.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /path/to/uploads -type f -mmin -5 -not -iwholename
'*.svn*'|xargs -r /usr/bin/svn add
sleep 2
/usr/bin/svn commit /path/to/uploads -m auto_upload
```

When I run this from shell I get:

```
find: missing argument to `-iwholename'
upload_images.sh: line 3: *.svn*: command not found
```

Do I need to escape out the asterisks or something? I'm confused. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Saw this error with **-exec** when I didn't end it with ```\;``` correctly

Answer (score 5):

You have a line break in the middle of your `find` command. This will cause `bash` to interpret it as two separate commands. Either make it a single line:

```
find /path/to/uploads -type f -mmin -5 -not -iwholename '*.svn*'|xargs -r /usr/bin/svn add
```

or use a `\` to continue it:

```
find /path/to/uploads -type f -mmin -5 -not -iwholename \
'*.svn*'|xargs -r /usr/bin/svn add
```

Sounds like maybe a copy+paste error.